Formik's isValid property stays false despite form validation passes by returning true
I would expect Formik's isValid property to get updated from false to true when the validation integrated to Formik passes but in one of the use cases this does not happen.
In more detail, my validation use case is related to adding and removing a search form filter field. The first step is adding a new filter and that works as expected: validation fails as the default value of the new filter is invalid and thus the the save-button gets correctly disabled (isValid property is false).  Second step is removing this "invalid" filter" straight after adding it, but unfortunately this works unexpectedly: the validation passes correctly (returns true) , but still the Formik's isValid property does not get updated to true (also the errors property does not get cleared).
The validation is integrated to Formik by using a property validationSchema={MySchema} in my <Formik (2.2.4-version). I also have validateOnMount and enableReinitialize as properties for my Formik, both without any explicit values given as parameters.
According to the console logs, the validation happens multiple times for each action like removal of that incomplete filter, and at least one of the validations happening in the middle returns also as a false value. Then again the last validation is always true like it should be and straight after that my console log inside the formik is printing the formik's isValid and errors properties, called inside useEffect:
  return (
    <Formik<FormState>
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validateOnMount
      enableReinitialize
      validationSchema={MySchema}
    >
      {(form: FormikProps<any>) => {
        const { values, errors, isValid, isSubmitting } = form

        // Log formik state using useEffect
        useEffect(() => {
          console.log("Formik State Updated:", {
            values,
            errors,
            isValid,
            isSubmitting
          })
        }, [values, errors, isValid, isSubmitting])

Anyways, the properties do not get updated despite the succesful validation.
Not sure if the reason could be behind those "extra" validations before the last successful validation - maybe the last succesful validation is somehow lost and some previous falsy validation is only used. I have recently updated to React 18, maybe this can have impact on this updating logic as well.
Then again, the isValid and errors properties will get correctly updated if I add some valid value to the new filter field. The funny thing is that in both cases the validationSchema is of course the same and I can see from my console logs that in both scenarios (removing the invalid filter/making invalid filter valid by appending correct value to it) the same validation logic is called and both return true, but still the formik properties gets updated correctly only in case of modifying the value.
